# Collapse navigation bar progmatically (but don't hide!)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I would like to have the the navigation bar collapsed at the root of the multilevel menu of my app, to avoid showing bar button items and empty space.

I can use the function below, but that will hide the navigation bar entirely which makes the statusbar overlapping with the content of the scrollview...

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true/false, animated: true)
```

The navigationbar is "Black" and "translucent" (not the deprecated "Black translucent").

(Problem:)
[image]

Here is what I want:
[image]